# Laravel webpack compile error bootstrap variable undefined

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, sass

I'm struggling for hours but don't know why I'm getting this on webpack compile command node version 12

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--8-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--8-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--8-5!./resources/assets/sass/main.scss
Module build failed: 
  font-weight: $font-weight-bolder; // Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari
              ^
      Undefined variable: "$font-weight-bolder".
      in /www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss (line 158, column 16)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss 4:14-267
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/pages/install.js ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss

ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: 
  font-weight: $font-weight-bolder; // Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari
              ^
      Undefined variable: "$font-weight-bolder".
      in /www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss (line 158, column 16)
    at /www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:195:19
    at /www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.callback (/www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:55:13)
    at Object.done [as callback] (/www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:8069:18)
    at options.error (/www/wwwroot/ship-hero.codersarray.com/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:294:32)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/pages/install.js ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss
```

Comment: Do you have `@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";` in your main.scss file?

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it here is the solution if anyone encounters the same problem the issue is with the bootstrap version according to package.json bootstrap version is ^4.0.0 but on running npm install 4.6 version is being installed that is causing the issue so I just install the specific version that is 4.0.0 changed the value in the package.json from ^4.0.0 to 4.0.0.